# Why is this condition never satisfied?

Tags: java

I don't know why this condition is never satisfied:
I'm comparing two ArrayList values, and it is always false.

```
if ( (Integer) results.get(rank) == (Integer) experts.get(j))
```

I'm debugging and I have exactly the same 2 values: 3043 and 3043
However it doesn't work.

thanks

Comment: If you were dealing with `int` s it would work...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `equals()`, not `==`. These are two different objects which represent the same value. So they are not `==` (different objects) but are `equals()` (same content).

Answer (score 3):

As Uri said you need to use the method .equals() for this instead of ==.

The == operator will only check to see if the references that are returned by
results.get(rank) and experts.get(j) are point to the same object (which they won't technically in this case)

There are two ways to kind of approach this.
1) If you know for a fact that experts will ALWAYS contain a reference then do the following:
experts.get(j).equals(results.get(rank))

2) If you are absolutely sure that you will ALWAYS have references on both sides do the following:
((Integer)results.get(rank)).intValue() == ((Integer)experts.get(j)).intValue()

Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

== will only do a value comparison for primitives.

Whenever dealing with Object types, including big-cap Integer, Long, etc. you need equals, not ==

Answer (score 1):

The `==` operator checks that two `Object` references are *identical*, not *equal* as we normally think.  This means that for `Integer` types, it checks that they refer to the same `Integer`.  If somewhere in your code you have 2 lines that create new `Integer`s with value 3043, instead of reusing one instance, then they are not referring to the same location in memory.  For your problem, it could be the case that the two collections have different object references in them because of that.

Another option, as `Integer` is an immutable type, is that you did not `new` anything, and instead maybe did a `valueOf`, and are aware that some implementations of `Integer` contain a cache of the first 128 or 256 integer values that are returned on `Integer.valueOf` invocations.

**From OpenJDK:**

```
public static Integer valueOf(int i) 
{
   if (i <  -128 || i  > 127) {
      return new Integer(i);
   }
   return valueOfCache.CACHE [i+128];
}
```

Maybe in your code you have a `String` equal to "3043", and you twice invoke `Integer.valueOf(thatString)` to get your `Integer` objects.  But this is mistaken as well, as you can see that at least 1 implementation will still internally `new` anything higher than 127, and you're back to the original problem.

```
Integer x = new Integer(120);  // as @polygenelubricants pointed out, these two will
Integer y = new Integer(120);  // never be == equal, but .equals equal, because new
                               // creates a brand new object in memory

Integer j = Integer.valueOf(15); // sometimes values < 128 will be cached, so j == k
Integer k = Integer.valueOf(15); // because valueOf will return the same cached object

Integer a = Integer.valueOf(3043); // 3043 is high enough that it probably isn't cached
Integer b = Integer.valueOf(3043); // so b is a reference to a different Integer
```

The bottom line: unless you explicitly took a single `Integer` and put it into both collections yourself, don't assume they are the same object.  Even if you know that they probably are the same object because you know that one JVM's implementation of `Integer` caches up to 4096, don't rely on that.  And always check an object for equality using `equals` unless you truly mean to ask whether they refer to the exact same location in memory.  For immutable objects like `Integer` and `String`, this is hardly ever needed.

Comment: `new` is never cached: it MUST return a new object. Caching would go against entire Java language foundation. What is cacheable is e.g. `valueOf`, by `class Integer`. The language itself wouldn't allow such caching from `new`.

Comment: Thanks @polygenelubricants, that's exactly what I was thinking!

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you could cast to `int` instead of `Integer` if this is appropriate in your application context.

Answer (score 0):

java objects must always be compared using `equals` method,  using `==` compares primitive values or actual object references, which obviously is different in this case; hence your equality never satisfies.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `==` operator checks for object identity in the sense of the same reference, they are not compared by the value they contain but by the reference they are allocated with.

It's safe to use `==` with primitives because they don't have references, so they are checked for equality in the sense of same value but when working with objects (and unfortunately `Integer` is an object that wraps an `int`) it checks if they are really the same object, not if they have the same value.

For example:

```
Integer x = new Integer(4);
Integer y = x;

//this will be true: same reference
assert(x == y)
```

if you want to keep `==` operator you should do

```
if (results.get(rank).intValue() == experts.get(j).intValue())
```

otherwise switch to equals operator:

```
// you don't need to cast them since equals will take care of checking 
//if they are of the same type
if (results.get(rank).equals(experts.get(j)))
```

Answer (score 0):

you should not compare two references with '==' until unless you want to check whether they are same objects or not , if you want to check whether they are equal use the Object.equals() method